# Arcpy modulo doesn´t show in Pycharm

Tags: python, arcpy

How can I integrate Arcpy into Pycharm, I tried by importing the module but it does not show, I do understand that the module only works on 2.x python.

Comment: This might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186718/error-using-pip-install-for-arcpy-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the

Comment: Thank you i actually solved by changing the enviroment to python 2.7 and going into Arcgis and assigning the python interpreter to pycharm, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you i actually solved by changing the enviroment to python 2.7 and going into Arcgis and assigning the python interpreter to pycharm, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

arcpy isn't available on PyPi (Python Package Index) and thus can't be installed through pip.

To use arcpy you need to install ArcMap, ArcGIS Pro, or ArcGIS Server. Any of these programs will create a Python installation with the arcpy package included. To access this from PyCharm, just set the project interpreter in PyCharm to the python.exe installed by ArcGIS.

For example: C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\python.exe

Comment: Thank you i actually solved by changing the enviroment to python 2.7 and going into Arcgis and assigning the python interpreter to pycharm, thank you so much.